# Length of filtered ArrayCollection in actionscript 3/flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, arraycollection

I need to display the number of items in a List component that has a filtered ArrayCollection as its data provider. I don't see a way to get the filtered collection's length. Anyone know? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Considering the code:

```
var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
ac.filterFunction =
    function(item:*):Boolean{
        return item > 3;
    };
ac.refresh();
```

You use `ac.length` to get filtered data length (6) and `ac.list.length` to get raw, unfiltered data length (10).

Comment: Thanks! I was trying that, but querying DURING the filter function instead of after the call to refresh(). Now it's working fine.